Git shows modified files with no actual differences
I'm working on a large and complex corporate project and I'm encountering an issue with Git and Visual Studio solution files (.sln). I have two .sln files that Git identifies as completely edited, but when I compare the files using WinMerge or Beyond Compare, there are no differences between the working area and the last commit. The files are identical, including EOL, white space, etc.
Here is what I've tried:
git diff <commit-sha> --ignore-space-change -- <path>

This results in no differences being found.
When I run the command without the --ignore-space-change flag:
git diff <commit-sha> -- <path>

Git shows the diff as @@ -1,20 +1,20 @@, indicating 20 rows deleted and 20 rows added, even though the content is exactly the same and the entire file is only 20 rows.
The most confusing part is that when I stash these two files, they are added to the stash area, but they still appear in the "Changes" section. Even if I restore the files using:
git restore --source=<commit-sha> <path> 

I am still seeing these files marked as modified.
I'm stuck on how to resolve this issue. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Could this be a matter of white spaces/line break?

I have had a problem like this in the past, and it had to do with the file being saved as UTF-X vs ANSI.

@RossBush using Beyond Compare with the command git difftool  , I see that both files are in UTF-8 with BOM. Additionally, in Beyond Compare, I enabled the rules to always consider important the following elements: leading whitespace, embedded whitespace, trailing whitespace, everything else, character case, orphan lines, and compare line endings (PC/Mac/Unix). Despite these settings, no differences are detected between the files.

"The most confusing part is that when I stash these two files, they are added to the stash area, but they still appear in the "Changes" section. Even if I restore the files using:"
This one is odd. Sounds a bit like broken folder/file permissions within the .git - Folder.

I checked the file and its parent folder permissions on Ubuntu, and confirmed they are identical in both the working directory and the latest commit. This morning, I performed a fresh clone of the repository, and interestingly, immediately after the clone, git highlights these two files as changed.

I think I found the problem!
In our .gitattributes file, there is a line:
*.sln text eol=crlf

After commenting out this line, Git no longer sees the past differences.
I’m not entirely sure why this happens, because the files were already in CRLF format and still are. If anyone has an explanation, I’d love to hear it.
